# Find the value of $k$ so that the given differential form is exact?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms

Find the value of $k$ so that the given differential form is exact.

$$(y^3 + k xy^4 - 2x) dx + (3xy^2 + 20 x^2y^3) dy$$

Comment: Do you know what "exact" means in this context?

Comment: I suppose you mean differential form. Do you have any notions about the relationships between Closedness and Exactness?

Answer (score 1):

A differential form on Euclidean space is exact if and only if its closed. It's pretty easy to solve the equation

$$\mathrm{d}\left( (y^3 + k xy^4 - 2x) \mathrm{d}x + (3xy^2 + 20 x^2y^3) \mathrm{d}y
\right) = 0$$

for $k$, if you actually compute the left hand side.

Answer (score 0):

You  want a function $f(x,y)$ such that its differential is the given form (this means to be an [exact form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential)), i.e:
$$
d f(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)dx +\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)dy=
(y^3+kxy^4-2x)dx +(3xy^2+20x^2y^3)dy
$$

In this case it is not difficult to find this function by simple inspection.  Note that it must be the sum of three monomial of the form $ ax^ny^m$ and for the first monomial we want:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}ax^ny^m=y^3 \quad \mbox{and} \quad \frac{\partial}{\partial y}ax^ny^m=3xy^2
$$
so the monomial must be $xy^3$ ( the integral with respect to $x$ of $y^3$ that is also the integral with respect to $y$ of $3xy^2$) .
In the same way you can see that the third monomial must be $-x^2$.

For the second monomial we have:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}ax^ny^m=kxy^4 \quad \mbox{and} \quad \frac{\partial}{\partial y}ax^ny^m=20x^2y^3
$$

so, integrating the derivative with respect to $y$ we find the monomial $5x^2y^4$ and this means that $k=10$.

So the searched function is $f(xy)=xy^3+5x^2y^4-x^2$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For
$$
\left(y^3+kxy^4-2x\right)\mathrm{d}x+\left(3xy^2+20x^2y^3\right)\mathrm{d}y
$$
to be exact, we need
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(y^3+kxy^4-2x\right)=3y^2+4kxy^3
$$
to be equal to
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(3xy^2+20x^2y^3\right)=3y^2+40xy^3
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ P dx+Q dy $$

is exact when

$$ \frac{\partial P} {\partial y} = \frac{\partial Q} {\partial x}$$

Carry out partial differentiations and simplify, $ k=10$.